# Set proxy credentials with Tesla.Adapter.Mint

Tags: elixir, http-proxy, tesla, elixir-mint

How can I set proxy credentials when using `Tesla.Adapter.Mint`. According `https://hexdocs.pm/tesla/Tesla.Adapter.Mint.html` It should be something like `{:http, "127.0.0.1", 8888, []}` , but where can I pass credentials just like: `{Tesla.Adapter.Hackney, [proxy: {"1.2.3.4", 1234}, proxy_auth: {"user", "pass"}]}`?

Comment: Have you tried to do it exactly the same as with `Hackney`?

Comment: Yes, but I wanna try Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [`proxy_headers` option](https://hexdocs.pm/mint/Mint.HTTP.html#connect/4-options):

> - `:proxy_headers` - a list of headers ([`Mint.Types.headers/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/mint/Mint.Types.html#t:headers/0)) to
>   pass when using a proxy. They will be used for the `CONNECT` request
>   in tunnel proxies or merged    with every request for forward proxies.

Comment: Just ran into this and wanted to provide a practical example:

"""
[
  proxy: {:http, "hostname.com", 7000, []},
  proxy_headers: [
    {"Proxy-Authorization",
     "Basic xyzpdq"}
  ]
]

In my case, the header value was "user:pass", Base-64 encoded.